# Share class instance between servlets

Tags: java, servlets, dependency-injection, jersey

I have a web.xml that defines a Jersey Servlet of class `org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer`, that is then configured with my own application class that extends `ResourceConfig` using:

```
    <init-param>
        <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
        <param-value>com.mypackage.AppResourceConfig</param-value>
    </init-param>
```

In my `AppResourceConfig` class I am constructing and registering Metric's `MetricRegistry` and `HealthCheckRegistry` instances.

Now I want to add a Metric's Health Check servlet like what is described at https://dropwizard.github.io/metrics/3.1.0/manual/servlets/ - That is, create the Metric's servlets and listeners to provide instances of the metrics registries to the servlet, such as:

```
public class MyHealthCheckServletContextListener extends HealthCheckServlet.ContextListener     {

    public static final HealthCheckRegistry HEALTH_CHECK_REGISTRY = new HealthCheckRegistry();

    @Override
    protected HealthCheckRegistry getHealthCheckRegistry() {
        return HEALTH_CHECK_REGISTRY;
    }

}
```

and (in web.xml)

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.example.MyHealthCheckServletContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

But taking this route would mean I have two versions of each. I know that the registries are declared as public static so I can just access them directly, but I'd prefer not to do it that way.

Is there a way to inject these directly into my own servlet `AppResourceConfig` class?